# How do I check an element's direct textContent?

Tags: javascript, html, innertext

Say I have an element structure like so

```
<div>
   This is direct text

   <div>
       This is text nested in a child element
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to check the direct text content of the parent div without checking the content of the inner children?

Consequentially if I had a structure like this

```
<div id="uppermost-div">
  <div>
     This is direct text

     <div>
       This is text nested in a child element
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And I checked this direct text content of the `#uppermost-div` I would expect to be null or empty string or something.

Is there a way to accomplish checking values like that in HTML/Javascript?

Comment: What code are you using now?

Comment: The duplicate question I linked to asks about jQuery, but there are vanilla JS answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```js
// Get the parent element somehow, you can just as well use
// .getElementById() or any other DOM method
var parentElement = document.querySelector('#myDiv');
// Returns the text content as a string
[].reduce.call(parentElement.childNodes, function(a, b) { return a + (b.nodeType === 3 ? b.textContent : ''); }, '');
```

Source: https://medium.com/@roxeteer/javascript-one-liner-to-get-elements-text-content-without-its-child-nodes-8e59269d1e71

Answer (score 0):

See comments.

```js
// Make a deep copy of the parent
let tempElement = document.getElementById("uppermost-div").cloneNode(true);

// Loop over the elements within the copy
tempElement.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(el){
  el.remove(); // remove the children
});

// Log the text of what's left
console.log(tempElement.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="uppermost-div">
  <div>
     This is direct text

     <div>
       This is text nested in a child element
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```